# SVG path lines are joined and don't have idea why

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to draw [this letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5QlY.png)
with svg path but on B letter, when I try to draw lines, the lines are joined and I don't understand why.
This is what I've done so far:

```
<path class="path" d="M0 117 L 0,0 65,0 65,25 30,25 30,45 65,45 65,70 30,70 30,90 65,90 65,117 0,117 z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent"/>
<path class="path" d="M80 117 L 125,0 125,100 z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent"/>

</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpc2rvtd/4/

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please explain what you mean by " the lines are joined"

Comment: See the jsfiddle demo, and look at that triangle, that was ment to be letter B not triangle

Comment: It's got 3 points (80, 117) (125,0) (125,100). That's generally consistent with what triangles have and not so much with the letter B

Comment: I'ts because i atarted to draw b letter and not finished, can you provide me an example of B letter drawn, because i can't get it

Comment: If you don't want the path to be closed, leave off the `z` at the end of the path data.

Comment: Yeap thanks, that worked, but i don't understand, with the first letter i didn't had this problem.

Comment: @LiviuDoloscan That's because the first path starts and ends at the same coordinates (0,117). If you leave the `z` there, you can omit the `0,117` at the end of the path data.